# $rootScope.$on not getting called after broadcast

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers and want to notify one controller that some event has happened from the other controller. For this I am trying to use angular broadcast but have been unsuccessful. Please find below my code:

firstController.js

```
 $rootScope.$on('xyz',function(){
    alert('Called');
 });
```

secondController.js

```
  $rootScope.$broadcast('xyz');
```

Can someone please help in identifying what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle which reproduces the problem? Why don't you use `$emit`?

Comment: If you are using `$rootScope` as a communication channel for events, use `$emit`. Equivalent, but much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use either a combination of:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast();
$scope.$on();

// or

$rootScope.$emit();
$rootScope.$on();
```

`$broadcast` dispatches the event downward to all child scopes, so you can listen to it with the `$scope` service.

However, `$emit` dispatches upward through the scope hierarchy, and since `$rootScope` is the at the highest level, you can use `$rootScope` to dispatch and listen to the same event. This is also much better in regards to performance since the event doesn't propagate down through multiple scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KV7BS/4/)

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('c1', function($rootScope, $scope){

    $scope.click = function() {
         $rootScope.$broadcast('xyz');
    }
});

app.controller('c2', function($scope){

   $scope.$on('xyz', function(){

    alert("clicked");
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

in firstController.js use $scope instead $rootScope

```
$scope.$on('xyz', function(event, args) {

   alert('Called')
});
```

Comment: No, it will not resolve the issue. `$broadcast`, as `$emit`, notifies the sender before to propagate the event.